# How would I group three unions together by date in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

[Here's an image if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT7lU.jpg)

I'm trying to join three tables of Japanese Sumo results together and order them by descending date from 2019. I managed to join them but can't figure out how to order them by date (BASHO). I'm working in Oracle Apex.

So far I've tried

```sql
Select a.* from sumo_2019 a
where a.Rikishi1_ID=12191
order by a.BASHO
Union
Select b.* from sumo_2018 b
where b.Rikishi1_ID=12191
order by b.BASHO
Union
Select c.* from sumo_2017 c
where c.RIKISHI1_ID=12191
Order by c.BASHO
```

and

```sql
Select a.* from sumo_2019 a
where a.Rikishi1_ID=12191
Union
Select b.* from sumo_2018 b
where b.Rikishi1_ID=12191
Union
Select c.* from sumo_2017 c
where c.RIKISHI1_ID=12191
Order by BASHO
```

but received errors both times (errors are
'Error at line 3/17: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended' for the first attempt and
'Error at line 9/10: ORA-00904: "BASHO": invalid identifier' for the second attempt

Comment: "but received errors both times." Please [edit] the question and include the complete error messages.

Comment: Use CTE table by "WITH" statement and apply group on it. not sure about Oracle but works in MSSQL.

Comment: I added the error messages. Sorry about that

Comment: Creating a CTE and ordering it by BASHO solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can `UNION` inside a sub-query and the `ORDER` the outer query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  Select *
  from   sumo_2019
  where  Rikishi1_ID=12191
Union
  Select *
  from   sumo_2018 b
  where  Rikishi1_ID=12191
Union
  Select *
  from   sumo_2017 c
  where  RIKISHI1_ID=12191
)
Order by BASHO;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sumo_2019 (BASHO, rikishi1_id) AS
  SELECT DATE '2019-01-01', 12191 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE sumo_2018 (BASHO, rikishi1_id) AS
  SELECT DATE '2018-01-01', 12191 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE sumo_2017 (BASHO, rikishi1_id) AS
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-01', 12191 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| BASHO | RIKISHI1_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 12191 |
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 12191 |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | 12191 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tgTjWLN8)